# Cloudbees support for Grails 2.2.2

Tags: grails, cloudbees

I'm trying to get my Grails application set up with Jenkins continuous delivery & deployment to Cloudfoundry, however it looks like 2.2.0 is the most recent supported Grails version.

Does anyone know if Cloudbees have plans to support Grails 2.2.2 in the near future?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Cloudbees allow you to install whatever version of Grails you want via Jenkins | Manage Jenkins | Configure System | Grails Installations...

Impressed!

Answer (score 0):

An easier way would be to use the Grails wrapper.

For more information please visit the following pages :

- http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/CI_With_Grails_And_Jenkins
- http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/guide/commandLine.html#wrapper